# yii2 active record search (2 базы данных)

Tags: sql, база-данных, yii2, activerecord, model

Есть 2 таблицы, в двух разных БД, на разных хостах.
`users(id,fio,address,...)` и `orders(id,user_id,date,...)` они связаны между собой

В модели `Orders` есть связь

```
public function getUser() {
  return $this->hasOne(Users::class, ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

как мне составить запрос чтобы получить все заказы где `date` меньше `2019-01-01`, пользователей `address` которых содержит `Komarova`?

я написал так:

```
$query = Orders::find()
  ->with([
    'user' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
      $query->andWhere(['like', 'address', 'Komarova']);
    }])
  ->andWhere(['<', 'date', '2019-01-01'])
  ->all();
```

Запрос работает но показывает все записи `orders` меньше даты;

У тех `orders` где у `user.address` адрес содержит `Komarova` присутствует под массив `user` c данными;

А тех `orders` где у `user.address` адрес НЕ содержит `Komarova` данного массива нет, это логично, так как не найдены совпадения по ключевому полю;

Только как добиться чтобы и самой записи не было если у пользователя не подходит адрес?

P.S. Если бы это была одна база или хотя бы один хост, проблема решаться легко через join, но нам это не поможет так как хосты разные.

Comment: [FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: еще варианты...